# Room Database: how to get reponse after insert data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i want to do something when insert data done but i don't know how to do that.
this is my Room Database structure.

Model

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
@Entity(tableName = "message_table")
data class MessageModel(
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    var messageId: String = "",
    var messageType: String? = null,
    var messageTimestamp: Long? = null,
    var messageData: String? = null,
    var messageSenderId: String? = null,
    var roomId: String = "",
    var isSeen: Boolean = false,
var uploadSuccess : Boolean = false
) : Serializable {
}
```

DAO interface

```
@Dao
interface MessageDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertMessageDAO(messageModel: MessageModel)
    ...
}
```

Repository

```
class MessageRepository(context : Context) {
    private val messageDAO : MessageDAO
    init {
        val messageDatabase: MessageRoomDatabase = MessageRoomDatabase.getInstance(context)
        messageDAO = messageDatabase.getMessageDao()
    }
     suspend fun insertMessageDAO(messageModel: MessageModel) = messageDAO.insertMessageDAO(messageModel)
     ...

}
```

ViewModel

```
class MessageViewModel(private val messageRepository: MessageRepository) : ViewModel() {
       fun insertMessageDAO(messageModel: MessageModel) = viewModelScope.launch {
           messageRepository.insertMessageDAO(messageModel)
       }
       ...
}
```

have a nice day, everyone!

Comment: You can do it it next line because you are already inside Coroutine scope . If u want to get the ID of newly inserted element you can make it return the id also . Also `viewModelScope.launch` runs on calling dispatcher i guess . u need to pass the Dispatcher also like `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO)`.

Comment: @ADM Actually there is no need to change dispatcher because Room automatically switches to a background thread before doing any I/O operations.

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot about it.  Room does it internally

Comment: thanks all you, i have a way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Id after successfully inserting the data into the database, add `Long` as return type as follows

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertMessageDAO(messageModel: MessageModel): Long
```

For a collection you can add `List<Long>` as return type

Comment: oh i understood. thanks so much